# Debugger hiding plugin for WinDbg?

Tags: debuggers, anti-debugging, windbg

Are there any good WinDbg hiding plugins like OllyDbg's? Or a plugin that's open source and still in development for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think such a plugin currently exists. However, if you're willing to implement a minimal windbg backend, you could extend [uberstealth](http://code.google.com/p/uberstealth), which unfortunately I've never come to finish as a project (actually I think anti-debugging is a dead anyway, but that's another story ;-)).
It's essentially IDAStealth, but with all debugger specific functionality factored out (there's a backend for IDA and Olly2). All you'd have to do is write a backend for Windbg (and fix the remaining bugs, I could help you with that though), all other code is debugger independent.
Should be less than a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: Such a plugin indeed does not exist, but you don't need one either. See my answer (posting this comment in case the accepted answer doesn't change).

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if plugins exist but you can write simple scripts like below to hide WinDbg on case to case basis.

- **`Peb->BeingDebugged`**

  ```
  r?$t0 = (ntdll!_peb *) @$peb;?? @$t0->BeingDebugged;eb (@$t0+2) 0;?? @$t0->BeingDebugged
  ```
- **`ZwSetInformationThread` (XP SP3 syscalls with `sysenter`)**

  ```
  bp ntdll!ZwSetInformationThread "r eip = $ip+0n12 ; r eax = 0; gc"
  ```
- **`ZwQueryInformationProcess`**

  syntax similar to `ZwSetInformationThread` in addition you would also need to fakeout DebugPort to NULL with

  ```
  ed poi(ADDRESS)  0
  ```

#### Reading

- Peter Ferrie's ["Ultimate" Anti-Debugging Reference](http://pferrie.host22.com/papers/unp2011.htm)

Comment: ah, but anti-debugging is fraught with special cases - you can't arbitrarily zero the DebugPort, for example, without first checking the PID, in case the process is being debugged intentionally.  Anyway, see my "Ultimate" Anti-Debugging Reference (pferrie.host22.com/papers/unp2011.htm) for a long list of tricks that you'd need to support (and some that you can't because they are direct kernel-returned data).

Comment: @peterferrie awesome reference, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @peterferrie thanks for the comment i wrote case to case basis just because i understand that there are lot of special cases anyway i have read your paper earlier quiet nice collection of antidebug tricks

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ScyllaHide](https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide). There are plugins for many debuggers, but it is also possible to use `InjectorCLI.exe` to inject ScyllaHide into any process. Here are the steps (for a 32 bit process, if you want a 64 bit process, replace every `x86` with `x64`):

1. Extract ScyllaHide ([download](https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide/releases)) anywhere;
2. Run `NtApiTool\x86\PDBReaderx86.exe` and when it's finished, copy `NtApiCollection.ini` to the same directory as `InjectorCLIx86.exe`;
3. Open `ScyllaTest_x86.exe` with WinDbg (x86) you should be in `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak`;
4. Execute `InjectorCLIx86.exe ScyllaTest_x86.exe HookLibraryx86.dll`;
5. Run (F5) in WinDbg.

Without using ScyllaHide:

[image: no hiding]

When using ScyllaHide:

[image: hiding]

This process works for any debugger, if you feel like it you can even make an actual plugin for WinDbg. It should be quite easy.

I just added an option to inject to a process by process id. You can do this with:

```
InjectorCLIx86.exe pid:1234 HookLibraryx86.dll
```

Comment: While this does seem to work for usermode applications, I have to test the associated TitanHide (https://github.com/mrexodia/TitanHide/blob/master/README.md) for Kernel mode. ScyllaTest reports NtQuerySystemInformation_KernelDebugger: DETECTED

Comment: Yes, ScyllaHide (and TitanHide for that matter) only work on usermode applications.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can download QEMU virtual machine with embedded WinDbg stub:
https://github.com/ispras/qemu/releases
https://github.com/ispras/qemu/tree/windbg

This stub allows debugging with WinDbg without enabling Windows debugging mode.