# Immunity debugger anti anti debug

Tags: disassembly, windows, anti-debugging, immunity-debugger

I using Windows, and I was wondering what is the best anti anti debug plugin that exist,
I tried to use hidedebug by Bob -> Team PEiD, but unfortunately it catch only the regular ways, I know that some of you will send me to the documents of all functions, but I'm looking for something that will make my life easier.
P.S:
I'm trying to debug just for fun and not for work :)
Thanks ahead.

Comment: precisely because of the fun you should not look for easy way, because you will miss all the fun in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ScyllaHide](https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide). There is no plugin for Immunity Debugger, but there is one for OllyDbg and that should make it trivial to port. Alternatively you can see [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/15451/2221) on how to hide any process with ScyllaHide regardless of the debugger you're using.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried patch_antidebug.py ?

https://github.com/theevilbit/immunity_scripts/archive/b0876ee751a00d0f0840be5a728de6b71ee50982/theevilbit_immunity_scripts-b0876ee7.tar.gz

Comment: unfortunately still the same, when i attach the debugger the program start to run, and detach itself from the debugger

Comment: Some particular program using some particular antidebug technique?